# What is the default "Internet/Navigator" of Android?

Tags: android, webkit, android-browser, chrome-for-android

I have been trying to investigate during these days exactly which browser is the one that comes by default in the android devices, but I am still confused.

If I understood this correctly, there are two possibilities depending on the device and Android version:

- "Android Browser" (its version depends only on the Android API? no updatable? based on WebKit?)
- "Chrome for Android" based on WebKit

I have done some tests with all the devices that I have been able to obtain and I have seen that approximately from version 5.0 or 5.1 of Android the default browser begins to be Chrome for Android. I think that because on versions smaller than 5.0 I cannot debug the app-browser connecting it to my PC and from the chrome://inspect and on versions higher I can do it, but maybe I'm wrong. I would like to ask if anyone can verify or correct that?

I have also realized that in versions higher than 5.0 there is an application called "Android System WebView" also available in PlayStore, but I would also like to ask: Does this have any relation to the type of browser installed (Android Browser or Chrome For Android)?

Comment: "I have been trying to investigate during these days exactly which browser is the one that comes by default in the android devices" -- device manufacturers are welcome to ship whatever they want. There is no fixed "default". At most, devices that are part of the Google Play ecosystem might be forced to ship a particular browser, but that has not precluded manufacturers from shipping *other* browsers along with it. Devices that are not part of Google Play do not have access to Chrome, as that is a proprietary browser.

Comment: thank you for your comment, @CommonsWare